Error With Mirroring and Weight Paint
I am having a very weird problem. I have a model that is mirrored and a rig that is symetrized. Everything looks fine but when the weight painting is applied it only applies to half of the rig/model, and when I move into pose mode the movements on the left are mirrored by the right. It is really weird and I have no idea what is happening.


Put the Mirror modifier above the Armature modifier (or apply it).

That seemed to work to get the weight paint to sort of work. But now the character gets offset from the armature. I can manually move the character back in place in object mode, but is there a way to have it not move?

The scale of both your model and armature haven't been applied in Object mode which could well be giving problems. Select each in turn and use Ctrl-A > Scale in Object mode.

Thank you so much, that fixed everything.
